# Allowing only local network access in NGINX for subdomain

Tags: nginx

Very similar question to this post: [Allowing only local network access in NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801772/allowing-only-local-network-access-in-nginx)

I have two subdomains running on nginx. [www].example.com and [vault].example.com. I would like for [vault].example.com to only be accessible from [www].example.com so I am trying to only allow the server ip to access the subdomain.

Following the post above, I created a private.conf

```
allow 192.168.1.0/24;
deny all;
```

But I am not sure where I should put my `include /etc/nginx/private.conf`. If I put it inside the nginx.conf file, it blocks the [www].example.com subdomain as well and I do not want that. I was unable to find a guide for where to put it inside the `/sites-available/vault` file as there is no http block and if I put it as the last line, it once again blocks access to [www].example.com from the public.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/vault

```
server {
    location {
    ...
    }
...
}

upstream backend {
...
}

server {
    location {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/254430/nginx-block-ip-based-on-uri-in-one-location/496051

Comment: @Martheen Yes that worked! But now I am trying to allow a specific page to be allowed... ```[vault].example.com/page``` and nothing else. How would I do this?

Comment: deny on server block, allow on location block